# 英語が残っている：ヘルプページ「プラス投票をする」のバッジ画像

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ヘルプページの [プラス投票をする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) にて表示されているバッジ画像が英語表記のままになっています。なお、別のページ「バッジ」の [一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) では日本語になっています。

Comment: リクエストいたしました、しばしお待ちを m_ _m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for feedback. I changed the pictures on the page. It should be fine now.